# automatically running an access macro

Tags: ms-access, macros, scheduled-tasks

I have an access macro, that I want to run automatically from a batch file which will be scheduled with windows scheduled tasks. At the moment however the batch file will not continue until I close the access window after it is finished. Is there a way to get access to do this silently?

The line I am using is

```
"c:\Programme\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\MSACCESS.EXE" "c:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\hom\Anwendungsdaten\BayWotch4\baywotch.db5" /excl /X Makro1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add a "Quit" action to the macro, or add a RunCode that runs a function with "DoCmd.Quit" in it?